# Unable to view table from database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table `jurnal_training` in my PhpMyAdmin

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| id_jurnal | kategori |   judul   |      isi_jurnal     | status |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1      |    WS    | Example 1 | content example 1   |   0    |
|    2      |    WS    | Example 2 | content example 2   |   1    |
|    3      |    WS    | Example 3 | content example 3   |   1    |
|    4      |    WS    | Example 4 | content example 4   |   0    |
.
.
.
```

and in PHP I need to view 'kategori', and 'jurnal' only which 'status' is 0;

here is my code:

```
<?
    $rec_limit = 9;
    $sql = "SELECT count(judul) FROM jurnal_training ";
    $retval = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($retval);
    $rec_count = $row[0];

    if( isset($_GET{'paging_view'} ) )
    {
        $paging = $_GET{'paging_view'} + 1;
        $offset = $rec_limit * $paging ;
    }
    else
    {
        $paging = 0;
        $offset = 0;
    }
    $left_rec = $rec_count - ($paging * $rec_limit);

    $sql = "SELECT * ".
    "FROM jurnal_training ".
    "LIMIT $offset , $rec_limit ".
    "WHERE status = 1";

    $count=1;
    $retval = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval))
    {
    echo "<tr >
            <td>",$count,"</td>
            <td>",$row['kategori'],"</td>
            <td><a href='index.php?do=view_jurnal&id_jurnal=",$row['id_jurnal'],"'>",$row['judul'],"</a></td>
            <td><a href='index.php?do=edit_jurnal&id_jurnal=",$row['id_jurnal'],"' class='process_button_s' >Edit</a><a href='index.php?do=delete_jurnal&id_jurnal=",$row['id_jurnal'],"'class='process_button_s'>Delete</a></td>
            <td><a href='index.php?do=train_process&id_jurnal=",$row['id_jurnal'],"' class='process_button'>Train Data</a></td>
        </tr>";
        $count++;
    }
    ?>
```

in variable $sql above, IF I don't add "WHERE status = 0" at the end of query, the tabel is viewed in PHP,. But if I put "WHERE status = 0" table is't viewed and got an error result :

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE status = 0' at line 1"

Comment: Please try to avoid using mysql_* in you codes, this is deprecated. It's time you start getting into prepared statements using PDO or mysqli. See this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM jurnal_training
LIMIT $offset , $rec_limit
WHERE status = 1
```

The `LIMIT` goes after the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM jurnal_training
WHERE status = 1
LIMIT $offset , $rec_limit
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have `limit` clause before `where` clause.

The order of clauses is important.  Please refer to the [Select Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for more details.

Also please note that `mysql` extension is now deprecated, please refer to "Recommended API" in "[Choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)" for recommended API to use.

Update your query as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * ".
"FROM jurnal_training ".
"WHERE status = 1 ". 
"LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit ";
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
SELECT * FROM jurnal_training LIMIT $offset , $rec_limit WHERE status = 1
```

Should be:

```
SELECT * FROM jurnal_training WHERE status = 1 LIMIT $offset , $rec_limit
```